# I am not who you think I am

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I put pieces together but i'm not a strategist.
I give advice but I'm not a life coach.
I come along with a message but I'm not a Prophet.
I am not religious but I am twisted.
No, I'm not your teacher, parent, nor a doomsayer.
I am not *who* you think I am.

I am...?

Comment: Would I have to injure you to get the message?

Comment: LoL, I think you have the same idea that I do, but mine doesn't seem to fit the first clue.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Then I think we *definitely* have the same idea.

Comment: I wonder what do you guys have in mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are...

> Clippy

I put pieces together but i'm not a strategist.

> You hold together pieces of paper

I give advice but I'm not a life coach.

> You make recommendations on how to improve the document I am composing.

I come along with a message but I'm not a Prophet.

> You pop up with that little text bubble. OR - You show up when I am writing a letter and say, "Looks like you're writing a letter!"

I am not religious but I am twisted.

> Paperclips are, by their very nature, twisted.

No, I'm not your teacher, parent, nor a doomsayer.

> Your suggestions are no replacement for the advice of a teacher or parent. Despite how most people may feel, your appearance does not denote the end of the world.

I am not who you think I am.

> Clippy's official name is Clippit.

I am...?

> One obnoxious office assistant.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this several times

Comment: @feelinferrety nicely done!  However line 3 it is actually referring to attachments in email.  You might edit the answer if you like

Comment: I did not actually think this was the right answer. XD

Comment: You should have added the clue, "I am hated by all"

Answer (score 4):

I am...?

> [Twisted Matrix](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

I put pieces together but i'm not a strategist.

> Data transmission happens in packets. These packets are reconstituted into a whole when received.

I give advice but I'm not a life coach.

> This framework provides some advice for how to use it.

I come along with a message but I'm not a Prophet.

> Messages are sent via the protocol.

I am not religious but I am twisted.

> Twisted.. this gave you away, my friend.

No, I'm not your teacher, parent, nor a doomsayer.

> This is true. You are none of these things.

I am not who you think I am.

> The name suggests "matrix", but it is actually a framework.

Comment: this could be a potential answer except line 2, there's something that fits better.  +1

Answer (score 2):

My guess is:

> Hint

Because

> Hints helps putting things together.

And

> Hint is definitely an advice, how to solve a problem

And

> hints always gave us a message :)

And

> it is twisted, because didnt see on stackexchange, just if you twist it with your mouse :D

And

> they gave us a lot of hints :D

Comment: good guess but it's not the answer